# Python Scrapy getting an error JSONDecodeError: Values must be separated by a comma while decoding the json string

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am trying to decode the json string using demjson library and i am getting an error - "JSONDecodeError: Values must be separated by a comma". I am scrapping a website using the python scrapy framework and i am taking the json string form the source code using regular expression and this is the json string i want to decode.

```
{
    'customerId':'',
    'productTitle':"Art & Funclay" Length 8cm. 12 Sticks",
    'price': '135',
    'categoryId': 'test',
    'availability': 'test',
    'sku':'BPSIM00140',
    'departmentName': "test",
    'categoryName': "a",
    'subCategoryName': "test",
    'brandName':"test",
    'pageURL':"test"
}
```

I hope the error is because of the extra " in 'productTitle':"Art & Funclay" Length 8cm. 12 Sticks". So how to decode the json string?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post a link to the endpoint that returns this in the response? Or, share the complete code you have so far.

Comment: If I paste thie JS snippet in my (Chrome) console, I get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`. Does the source webpage render fine with no console error in your browser?

Comment: `demjson.decode(r'"Art & Funclay\" Length 8cm. 12 Sticks"')` works. `demjson.decode(r'"Art & Funclay" Length 8cm. 12 Sticks"')` doesn't

Answer (score 1):

```
s = """
{
    'customerId':'',
    'productTitle':"Art & Funclay" Length 8cm. 12 Sticks",
    'price': '135',
    'categoryId': 'test',
    'availability': 'test',
    'sku':'BPSIM00140',
    'departmentName': "test",
    'categoryName': "a",
    'subCategoryName': "test",
    'brandName':"test",
    'pageURL':"test"
}
"""
s = re.sub(r"'productTitle':\s*\"(.+?)\",", "'productTitle': '\\1',", s)
json_obj = demjson.decode(s)
```